# Подсказка боту в виде буквы

Tags: python

Всем привет, я создал программу, которой загадываешь слово, она его пытается угадать рандомным методом, единственная её подсказка-количество букв в слове. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы если слово состоит из 5 или более букв, то через каждые 1 миллион строк давала подсказку в виде буквы(от миллиона-первая буква, от двух миллионов-вторая буква и т.д). Кто знает, как это можно реализовать?
Вот мой код:

```
import random
a = 1
Ivan = input('''Введи желаемое слово:
''')
while True:
 symbols = 'ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮЁ'
 word = ''.join([random.choice(symbols) for x in range(len(Ivan.upper()))])
 if (word != Ivan.upper()):
  print(str(a) + '.' + word)
  a += 1
  continue
 else:
   print(str(a) + '.' + word)
   break
input()
```

Comment: много кто знает, как можно реализовать. Сначала сформулируй конкретно, что именно реализовать. Например, как должна выглядет эта самая подсказка и что после этого должно происходить?

Comment: Загадываю слово, например "Подушка", чтобы отгадать это слово, нужно очень много вариантов набора букв, тем самым и много времени. Чтобы не ждать так долго, можно сделать подсказки. Когда a равен миллиону, то следующие строки с набором букв будут начинаться на первую букву загаданного слова, в данном случае на букву П. Проходит еще миллион строк, и открывается вторая буква и так далее.

Comment: и в чем проблема? взять первую букву? начать случайный набор букв с этой буквы? что-то еще? Вопрос сейчас очень широкий и не понятно, какой именно ответ нужен.

Comment: Ну так можно считать количество итераций. Как достигло миллиона, берешь переменную, присваиваешь ей П, например. И уже итерируешься в цикле word = ''.join([random.choice(symbols) for x in range(len(Ivan.upper()))]) не до количества букв в слове, а -1 буква. Затем объединяешь П и сгенерированное слово и выполняешь проверку. Не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться...

Comment: Нужно после каждого миллиона строк добавлять по буквы и начинать рандомный набор букв с этих букв, так попонятнее будет? Просто я не очень хорошо видимо объясняю, надеюсь на помощь